# Changing class for label

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have some validation in place but need to hide the div error, or add class 'hidden' on success. I have included links to the plugin im using. And you can see in my demo when you fill out a field, a space is added for the error label under each input. http://cuberocigars.com/bugler/xml.request.php

HTML

```
<div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-coupon" name="address1" placeholder="Street Address" id="address1">
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS - This is the highlight and success

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Validate
// http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

    $('#contact-form').validate({
    rules: {

      address1: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      }

    },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element) {
            element

            .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success')


        }
  });

}); // end document.ready
```

CSS

```
label.error {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: red;
        padding: 2px 8px;
        margin-top: 2px;
    }
```

Comment: Where is your complete validation code?  Since you tagged this for the Validate plugin, where is `.validate()`?  Where is the HTML for the form?

Comment: Any errors?  Are you sure success is being called?  Are you sure element is instanceof jQuery?

Comment: you can view my example here http://cuberocigars.com/bugler/xml.request.php if you fill out one of the fields you will notice a space is added which is an empty label

Comment: We need you to post all the relevant code **here**.  Otherwise, to future readers, this question is useless without your website.

Comment: I am using validation from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Where is your complete `.validate()` function?  You know... the part that `.success` is inside.  Also, the form's rendered HTML.  I'd like to include a working demo with my answer and you're making it difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `unhighlight:` callback instead of `success:`...

```
highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success')
}
```

[As per documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions):

> **unhighlight**, Callback, Default: Removes the errorClass
>   Called to revert changes made by option `highlight`, same arguments as `highlight`.

Comment: I ended up using errorContainer Selector thanks for your help